# Apply a formula from check box in VBA

Tags: vba, checkbox, excel-formula

I've been struggling with this for a while now. I have this code:

```
 Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
 If OptionButton1.Value = True Then
 Sheets("Sheet1").Select
 Range("J4").Select
 Selection.FormulaArray = "=IFERROR(INDEX(C$2:C$14, SMALL(IF($B$2:$B$14=1, ROW($B$2:$B$14)-1),ROWS(G$2:G2))),"")"
 Selection.Columns.AutoFit

 ElseIf OptionButton1.Value = False Then
 Range("J4").Value = " "
 End If

 End Sub
```

Where I'm trying to get the formula performed in cell J4. It just won't do it! And I don't really get why!

Comment: Does the formula work when added by itself to the sheet as an array formula?

Comment: Yes, it does what i want to to exactly! Just not as smoothly or as flexibly.

Answer (score 0):

The array formula [must be R1C1 format not A1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837104.aspx).

So:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
If OptionButton1.Value = True Then
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("J4").FormulaArray = "=IFERROR(INDEX(R2C[-9]:R14C[-9], SMALL(IF(R2C2:R14C2=1, ROW(R2C2:R14C2)-1),ROWS(R2C[-5]:R[-2]C[-5]))),"""")"
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("J4").Columns().AutoFit
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("J4:J40").AutoFill
ElseIf OptionButton1.Value = False Then
    Range("J4").Value = " "
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks so much for your hel - im getting really close to solving my problem.



Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()

If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("J4:J40").FormulaArray = "=IFERROR(INDEX(C$2:C$14, SMALL(IF($B$2:$B$14=1, ROW($B$2:$B$14)-1),ROWS(G$2:G2))),"""")"
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("J4:J40").Columns().AutoFit

ElseIf CheckBox1.Value = False Then
    Range("J4:J40").Value = " "
End If
    
End Sub



I just need the (G$2:G2) to occur sequentially {e.g. ((G$2:G3), (G$2:G4)), (G$2:G5)) etc}when the formula is repeated across the rane. Is this possible?

Comment: Doesn't an array formula require the range that the values are going into? i.e. change ".Range("J4").FormulaArray" to the array needed like ".Range("J4:P23").FormulaArray"

Comment: @jap7675 sorry for the delay I missed your last comment I have edited the answer.  I hope you had found the answer else where.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the only problem, but consider changing this line:

```
Selection.FormulaArray = "=IFERROR(INDEX(C$2:C$14, SMALL(IF($B$2:$B$14=1, ROW($B$2:$B$14)-1),ROWS(G$2:G2))),"")"
```

to this:

```
Selection.FormulaArray = "=IFERROR(INDEX(C$2:C$14, SMALL(IF($B$2:$B$14=1, ROW($B$2:$B$14)-1),ROWS(G$2:G2))),"""")"
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks so much for your hel - im getting really close to solving my problem.



Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()

If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("J4:J40").FormulaArray = "=IFERROR(INDEX(C$2:C$14, SMALL(IF($B$2:$B$14=1, ROW($B$2:$B$14)-1),ROWS(G$2:G2))),"""")"
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("J4:J40").Columns().AutoFit

ElseIf CheckBox1.Value = False Then
    Range("J4:J40").Value = " "
End If
    
End Sub



I just need the (G$2:G2) to occur sequentially {e.g. ((G$2:G3), (G$2:G4)), (G$2:G5)) etc}when the formula is repeated across the rane. Is this possible?

Comment: Do you think you could explain in words what you're trying to do? I've been playing with your formula and it does some really weird stuff.  I'm not sure, for example, why you bother referencing column G at all.  Maybe this is my opportunity to learn something, but it seems like ROWS(G$2:Gn) would give you a row count at the current row. That's exactly what ROW($B$2:$B$14)-1 gives you.  Also, if one of the values in column B is not 1, the "IF" returns FALSE causing SMALL to error.  Only, I'm observing that as an array formula it doesn't error but seems to shift the rows up.  Confusing.